# d3.js: SVG bars appear outside the svg area

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm new to d3.js and I am building a simple bar chart.  The code shown below shows bars at the very bottom of the browser window, not within the svg region in the html code.

Here's the html code:

```
<div class="C2_01">First paragraph.</div><br>

<div class="C2_02">Second paragraph.</div><br>

<svg></svg>
<script src="JS\D3_BarChart.js"></script>

<div class="C2_04">Third paragraph.</div>
```

Here's the d3 javascript code:

```
var dataArray = [23, 13, 21, 14, 37, 15, 18, 34, 30];

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
          .attr("height","20%")
          .attr("width","20%");

svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataArray)
    .enter().append("rect")
          .attr("height","250")
          .attr("width","30")
          .attr("x", function(d, i) {return (i * 60) + 25})
          .attr("y","50")
          .attr("fill","white");
```

My only question is, why are the bars showing outside the svg area, far to  the bottom of the page?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need to select the existing svg element instead of appending a new one.

```
var svg = d3.select("svg") // Not append
          .attr("height","20%")
          .attr("width","20%");
```

Full code to view all the bars on a white background.
http://jsfiddle.net/jg83ed91/5/

```
var dataArray = [23, 13, 21, 14, 37, 15, 18, 34, 30];

d3.select("svg")
  .attr("height", "20%")
  .attr("width", "100%") // Full width to show all bars
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(dataArray)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("height", "250")
  .attr("width", "30")
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return (i * 60) + 25
  })
  .attr("y", "50")
  .attr("fill", "black"); // On white background
```

Comment: That makes sense, but unfortunately, that doesn't do it.  The bars now disappear completely.

Comment: See the updates above. All the bars should now display between "Second..." and "Third..."

Comment: Your fiddle example shows it working, but on my chart I now have the svg element in the correct place (you were right about select vs append), but I still don't see bars.  I even reproduced the code exactly as you show it on a stand-alone htm page, but no bars show.

Comment: Are you getting console errors? Can you post the full html of your page? Or is it the same?

Comment: Now I'm okay.  Your fiddle code didn't have the reference to the script file, so I included <script src="JS\D3_BarChart-StackOverflow.js"></script> and your example works now.  Thanks very much for your help.  I upvoted your answer.